# Отображение булевых данных с использованием plt.bar()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, анализ-данных, визуализация

Дана Excel таблица

[image: таблица]

с переменной `Smoking`, где даны только варианты `True` или `False`. Я хочу отобразить эту инфу в формате `grouped bar`, где для каждого варианта возраста у меня будет по две колонны, `True` и `False`. Что-то вроде этого:

[image: пример]

Использую питон и библиотеки pandas и matplotlib.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Ваш код не предоставлен, исходные данные в воспроизводимом виде не предоставлены. Закрывать надо такие вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [seaborn.barplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x="Age", y="Count", hue="Smoking", 
            data=df.groupby(["Age", "Smoking"]).size().reset_index(name="Count"))
```